# Jquery like function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this list which shows nine posts on my page. Each post have a "like"-function tied to it, so that a user can like each post, and see the number of likes update. This is achieved by a simple ajax call.

The user can also load more posts by pushing button so that nine more post are appended via ajax. This works fine, but my problem is with the like-function which is tied to the posts which are loaded via the load more-function.

This function has one parameter which is the id of the last inserted post (iden). It takes all the li in the ul and creates a list called $listItems. It then iterates over $listItems, checks if the id of the post is less than the last inserted and then ties a click event to the "like"-symbol of the post. The function is called each time you push the "load more" button.

```
function likenmore(iden) {

   var $listItems = $('ul.statuses').find('li');
   var i = 0;
   console.log($listItems);     
   $.each($listItems, function (index, element) {
    var id = $(this).attr('class');
    if (id < iden) 
    {
    console.log(id);
    i++;
    $(".likemore" + i).live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'like.php',
                data: "id=" +id + "&num=1",
                success: function(data) {   
             $('.hearts' + id).html(data);                              
             }
    }); 
    }); 
    }
    });
 }
```

There are two problems with this function.

1. When I push the load more button the first time, I can like the first eight of the nine newly appended posts, but the click event is not tied to the ninth and last one. If I do console.log(id) I can see that the id of the last one is not printed, event though it is in the list $listItems, which I have already checked.
2. When I push the load more button the second time, all of the posts, not just the ones with a id lower than the last inserted, gets a click event tied to them, which creates double posting when a button is clicked. I do not understand why the if condition doesn't work the second time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is deprecated in 1.7+ and removed in 1.9 consider using `.on()` like this.

Delegate on the closest static parent or document for dynamically added elements

```
 $(document).on("click",".likemore" + i, function (e) {
```

Comment: try to use the delegate event handler. Like anton says in above comment, it is deprecated. May be it is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, thank's for responding. I changed to jquery 1.10.2 and replaced my live functions with de the delegate event handler, but the exet same problem i still there. any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, and did you do it exactly the same way as i wrote it?

Comment: No. no errors, I did it like this:   $('ul.statuses').on("click",".likemore" + i, function (e) {

Comment: Try and see if this works $(document).on('click','.likemore'+i,function(e){

Comment: Are you able to get the `.on('click','likemore' +i` eventhandler outside the likenmore function so it triggers on document load?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34694/discussion-between-user1009453-and-anton)

Comment: I'm at work atm, won't be able to start a chat discussion now.